# How to make WordPress Rest API parameters accessible without authentication?

Tags: wordpress, rest, wp-api

How can I make certain parameters of the WordPress Rest API accessible to *anyone* without first being authenticated – for example, the `page` parameter doesn't work (where `blog` is a custom post type) in this query:

`mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/blog?page=2&per_page=20`

I've seen that in the past it's been possible to make these params available, for [instance](https://torquemag.io/2014/11/preparing-wordpress-site-power-single-page-web-app/) :

```
add_filter( 'json_query_vars', function( $valid_vars ) {

    $valid_vars[] = 'offset';

    return $valid_vars;
});
```

Is there any way to do something similar with today's version of the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem, I've solved it. The `page` parameter is actually publicly available, `offset` is the one you need authentication for.

The reason the API didn't paginate was because the request url didn't have the `paged` query string set. Every time I tried to add it with the `params` option of the WordPress Node API, it didn't work:

`wpapi.getNews().params('paged', 'paged').perPage( perPage ).page( pageNumber ).then(data=>`

It didn't work because the request url created by the API seemed to always put the `page` parameter before the `paged` one, which resulted in `paged` being ignored when the query actually runs.

So in the end, I created a custom query (bit of a hacked way to do it, but it worked) like so:

Register the route:

`wpapi.getNews = wpapi.registerRoute('wp/v2', '/news/(?P<customQuery>)');`

Usage:

`wpapi.getNews().customQuery('?paged&per_page=20&page='+pageNumber).then(data =>`

Using the above, you can build any query, in any order you want. This helped me get the correctly paginated result. Also, we see 'getNews' here because I registered a route for accessing my custom post type called `news`.